# Parse XML with repeated pattern of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Can you please give me some ideas on the best way to parse an XML document in C#?

```
<RESPONSE>
  <FNAME>user1</FNAME>
  <LNAME>lastname1</LNAME>
  <ADDRESS>
     <LINE1>line 1 for user 1</LINE1>
     <LINE2>line 2 for user 1</LINE2>
     .....
     .....
  </ADDRESS>
  <FNAME>user2</FNAME>
  <LNAME>lastname2</LNAME>
  <ADDRESS>
     <LINE1>line 1 for user 2</LINE1>
     <LINE2>line 2 for user 2</LINE2>
     .....
     .....
  </ADDRESS>

</RESPONSE>
```

This is data returned from an online XML service and it is obviously not really well formed, as the nesting is not applied properly for each of the different elements. Is there a way I can avoid a line by line parsing and text comparison?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the returned XML? What elements do you want to parse out?

Comment: Be careful. "Well-formed" has a specific meaning in XML and your document *is* well-formed. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element

Comment: XPath **selects** nodes from an XML tree (already parsed). Retagging.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader("response.xml");
while (xml.Read())
{
    switch (xml.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            {
                if (xml.Name == "RESPONSE") Console.WriteLine("Response: ");
                if (xml.Name == "FNAME")
                {
                    Console.Write("First Name: ");
                }
                if (xml.Name == "LNAME")
                {
                    Console.Write("Last Name: ");
                }
                if (xml.Name == "ADDRESS") Console.WriteLine("Address: ");
                if (xml.Name == "LINE1")
                {
                    Console.Write("Line 1: ");
                }
                if (xml.Name == "LINE2")
                {
                    Console.Write("Line 2: ");
                }
            }
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xml.Value);
            }
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I upvoted this because I don't really see a way to parse this XML into separate objects other than reading through it sequentially.  Like the OP said, the XML is not nested in a way that would make this easier.

Answer (score 2):

[Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is the the modern way of parsing XML using .NET

the following snippet will give you access to all of the FNAME elements

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var fname in doc.Root.Elements("FNAME") {
  // fname.Value has the element value
}
```